# Velocity distribution function for cyclotron motion

Tags: plasma-physics

Let us be a plasma at temperature $T_e$. Electrons in it have a VDF (velocity distribution function) :

$$
f_e(\textbf{v})\text{d}^3\textbf{v}=\left( \frac{m}{2\pi k_BT_e}\right) ^{3/2} \times \exp\left[-\frac{m\textbf{v}^2}{2k_B T_e} \right]\text{d}^3\textbf{v}
$$

Assume now that there is a constant and static magnetic field along the $\textbf{e}_z$ direction. Electrons will have a cyclotron motion due to Lorentz force, at frequency $\omega_c=eB/m$ around magnetic field lines. If we neglect collisions, an electron will have a velocity
$$
\textbf{v}=\textbf{v}_\theta+\textbf{v}_z,
$$
in cylindrical coordinates. What is the proper way to go from the VDF above to the new one in $f_e(v_\theta,v_z)$ ?

**What I already did:** I made the variable change in cilyndrical coordinates and got

$$
f_e(\textbf{v})\text{d}^2\textbf{v}=2\pi v_\theta\left( \frac{m}{2\pi k_BT_e}\right)  \times \exp\left[-\frac{m\textbf{v}^2}{2k_B T_e} \right]\text{d}^2\textbf{v}
$$

If $\textbf{v}$ was $v_r$ I would be okay, but here I have doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motion is circular in the directions perpendicular to the field-line along $\mathbf{e}_z$.  This means,

\begin{eqnarray}
v_x & = & v_\perp \cos(\omega_c t) \; , \\
v_y & = & v_\perp \sin(\omega_c t) \; , \\
\end{eqnarray}

with $v_\perp$ and $v_z$ independent of time.  Thus, $v^2$ is independent of time

\begin{equation}
v^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2 = v_\perp^2 + v_z^2 \; .
\end{equation}

The volume element is cylindrical, with $v_\perp$ playing the role of the cylindrical radius (it is customary to write $v_\perp$ not $v_\theta$):

\begin{equation}
d^3v = 2 \pi v_\perp d v_\perp d v_z \; .
\end{equation}

The factor of $2\pi$ arises from the symmetry about the fieldline.  The final result is thus:

\begin{equation}
f_e \, d^3 v =\left( \frac{m}{2\pi k_BT_e}\right) ^{3/2} \exp\left[-\frac{m}{2k_B T_e} \left( v_\perp^2 + v_z^2 \right) \right] 
\, 2 \pi v_\perp d v_\perp d v_z
\end{equation}

If you prefer to retain the gyroangle $\phi$ (which is the velocity angle swept by the circular motion), then in the volume element, set $2 \pi \rightarrow d\phi$.